# Get the count of longest streak including the break point

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I am working on the problem where I have to get the count of streak with max value, but to get the exact result I have to count that point as well where the streak breaks. My table looks like this

```
+-----------------+--------+-------+
| customer_number | Months | Flags |
+-----------------+--------+-------+
|               1 |     12 |     1 |
|               1 |      1 |     1 |
|               1 |      2 |     1 |
|               1 |      3 |     1 |
|               1 |      4 |     1 |
|               1 |      5 |     1 |
|               1 |      8 |     1 |
|               1 |      9 |     1 |
|               1 |     10 |     1 |
|               1 |     11 |     1 |
|               6 |     12 |     1 |
|               6 |      1 |     1 |
|               6 |      2 |     1 |
|               6 |      3 |     1 |
|               6 |      4 |     1 |
|               6 |      5 |     4 |
|               6 |      9 |     1 |
|               6 |     10 |     1 |
|               6 |     11 |     1 |
|               7 |      5 |     1 |
|               8 |      9 |     1 |
|               8 |     10 |     1 |
|               8 |     11 |     1 |
|               9 |      9 |     1 |
|               9 |     10 |     1 |
|               9 |     11 |     1 |
|              10 |     11 |     1 |
+-----------------+--------+-------+
```

and my desired output is

```
+----------+--------------------+
| Customer | Consecutive streak |
+----------+--------------------+
|        1 |                 10 |
|        6 |                  6 |
|        7 |                  1 |
|        8 |                  3 |
|        9 |                  3 |
|       10 |                  1 |
+----------+--------------------+
```

the code I have

```
SELECT customer_number, max(streak) max_consecutive_streak FROM (
SELECT customer_number, COUNT(*) as streak
FROM 
(select *,
             (row_number() over (order by customer_number) -
              row_number() over (order by customer_number)
             ) as counts
      from table1
     ) cc
group by customer_number, counts
)
GROUP BY 1;
```

It is working good but for customer_number 6 it returns 5 but I want it to be 6, means it should count 4 as well in its longest streak as the streak breaks at this point. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: Your current table is not really suitable for gaps and islands, because it is lacking a column which provides the _ordering_ for your data.  Without that column, the data, as you have shown it, does not really exist that way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you are right I have added that column now thing is it might become more complicated to explain, although, I am trying to solve the gaps and island problems as I was trying to get max consecutive months that can span over different years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cte` with `row_number`:

```
with cte(r, id, flag) as (
  select row_number() over (order by c.customer_number), c.* from customers c
),
freq(id, t, f) as (
  select c2.id, c2.f, count(*) from 
     (select c.id, (select sum(c1.flag!=c.flag) from cte c1 where c1.id=c.id and c1.r <= c.r) f from cte c) 
  c2 group by c2.id, c2.f
)
select id, max(f) from freq group by id;
```

Comment: sorry, I can not use CTEs as they are not allowed, although I did tried to convert it to sub queries but couldn't get results